# changing n queens problem with backtracking

Tags: python, backtracking, n-queens

I have an N queen program with backtracking (it generates all the possible solutions) that I want to change it in a way that it places the queens in the half of each column and half of each row(number of columns and rows are even). for example if I have 6 columns and 4 rows it puts 2 queens in each row and 3 queens in each column.

Output example:

```
[[1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0]]
```

The problem is when I run my script I get this error:

```
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

I don't know which part I'm doing wrong.
here is my code:

```
k = 1
global N
t=4
N=t-1
w=(t-1)*2
def printSolution(board): 

    global k 
    print(k, "-\n") 
    k = k + 1
    for i in range(N*2): 
        for j in range(N*2): 
            print(board[i][j], end = " ") 
        print("\n") 
    print("\n") 

def isSafe(board, row, col) : 

    for i in range (row):
            for j in range(col): 
                if np.sum(board[i][j])>N: 
                    return False

    for j in range (col):
            for i in range(row): 
                if np.sum(board[i][j])> int(t/2): 
                    return False

    return True

def solveNQUtil(board,row, col) : 


    if col>=w and row<t:
            col=0
            row+=1
    if (col == w and row==t): 
            printSolution(board) 
            return True

    res = False
    for i in range(N): 
        if (isSafe(board, row, col)): 

            board[row][col] = 1; 


            res = solveNQUtil(board, row,col+1 ) or res; 

    return res 


def solveNQ() : 

    board = np.zeros((t,w)) 

    if (solveNQUtil(board, 0,0) == False): 

        print("Solution does not exist") 
        return
    return
solveNQ()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hit the last element on the board, you will have `col = w` and `row = t-1`. So in `solveNQUtil` you will enter the first block and set `col = 0` and `row = t`. Then, in the next check you don't have `col == w` but `col = 0`. So you continue and later attempt to access `board[row]` which is then of course out of bounds.

I guess the test whether you reached the end should be the *first* thin in `solveNQutil` and should read something like `if col == w and row == t - 1`?